# Adding a row to a table dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, html-table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    periodicRefresh();
}, 9000);
})
```

.

```
function periodicRefresh()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'include/ajaxActions.php',
        data: "action=displayLastEvent",

        success: function(msg){
            var newid = $(msg).attr("id");
                    current = $("#list tr:first").get(0).id;
                    if(newid != currentfirstrow){
                        $("#list").prepend(msg);
                lastrow = current-19;
                $('#'+lastrow).remove();
                    }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is an example of what the table row looks like:

```
<tr id="5094"  style="background:White;">
  <td class="tdstd">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a little hard to answer, without knowing how the XML that is returned from "ajaxActions.php" and your AJAX call is formatted. Also, I'm assuming that "currentfirstrow" is a global javascript variable accessible inside any function?

```
function periodicRefresh()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'include/ajaxActions.php',
        data: "action=displayLastEvent",

        success: function(xml){
            var newfirstrow = $(xml).find("name_of_xml_node_that_contains_newly_returned_id").text();
            if(newfirstrow != currentfirstrow){
                //do add new row()
            }
        },
}
```

Comment: the output of ajaxActions.php is only: 

<tr id="5094"  style="background:White;">
  <td class="tdstd">
  </td
</tr>

Comment: Ah okay, so you're just outputting html essentially. Good to know, let me think about it for a bit.

Comment: Thanks I found how to do that part with html and its edited in the my post

Comment: Okay, well then I would assume that you could just prepend the returned HTML to the table. This should add the html immediately after the <table> tag. I think? Sorry, it's been a while. :D

if(newfirstrow != currentfirstrow) {
     $("#TableID").prepend(msg);
}

Comment: Excellent, glad we got it all sorted out. :)

Answer (score 1):

At first ids aren't allowed to be numbers. They should start with a letter, then followed by a number. So you need to follow a different naming convention for your ids.

I am not sure if that's what you are asking for, but you can get the id of the first row with something like this:

```
$("table tr:first").get(0).id
```